# Usando aritmética de punteros, modifique todos los caracteres de la cadena para que pase de minus a mayus

Tags: c

> Usando aritmética de punteros, modifique todos los caracteres de la cadena para que pase de *minús* a *mayús* con 2 punteros: uno `*A` y `*B`, con `B` como contenedor de una string, luego de eso a `C` se le da la dirección de memoria del caracter del centro de la string.

¿Por qué ni siquiera entra al ciclo?

```
x = strlen(*(B + i));
for ( i = 0; i < x; i++)
{
    *(B + i) = toupper(*(B + i));
    printf("\n");
}
```

y esta parte ni siquiera se imprime:

```
C=&*(B + x);
printf("%s",*C);
```

Comment: Si el ciclo no se ejecuta ni una vez es porque `x` vale 0.

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo una cadena tal que

```
char cadena[] = "hola a todos";
```

Tenemos entonces dos punteros `A` y  `B`:

```
char *A = cadena;
char *B = cadena;
```

Te dice que `B` lo utilices como contenedor de la cadena ... aquí no me queda claro si se refiere a que tienes que dejar `B` apuntando al inicio de la cadena o si ese puntero se debe utilizar para apuntar a la cadena de destino... Lo digo porque:

- Si tienes que modificar la cadena original, con un puntero te basta
- Si tienes que actualizar una segunda cadena, entonces el enunciado se contradice, pues dice claramente **modifique todos los caracteres de la cadena**

El caso es que no necesitas llamar a `strlen` en ningún momento. Todas las cadenas de C terminan (o deberían terminar) con el caracter nulo, luego te puedes limitar a iterar la cadena hasta que llegues a dicho caracter. Para resolver el puntero C, basta con incrementarlo únicamente la mitad de las veces.

Asumiendo que hay que escribir en una segunda cadena:

```
char cadena1[] = "abcdefghi";
char cadena2[100];

char *A = cadena1;
char *B = cadena2;
char *C = cadena2;

for(int i=0; *(A+i)!=0; i++)
{
    if (i%2 != 0) C++;

    if (*(A+i) >= 'a' && *(A+i) <= 'z')
        *(B+i) += *(A+i) + ('A' - 'a');
    else
        *(B+i) = *(A+i);
}
```

También puedes usar `strlen`, pero en este caso debes estar apuntando **al inicio** de la cadena:

```
int length = strlen(A);
char *C = B + length/2;
```

nota que `strlen` espera recibir un puntero. Si no le pasas una dirección de memoria no podrás fiarte de los valores que obtengas

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, solo que en este caso lo que necesitaba era digamos un "vector de punteros"(?), basicamente que fuera como un array-1D de caracteres, osea, cargar el vector(diagamos char *B[30] )con una string, y volverla mayuscula en ese mismo vector, y luego usar el  *C para apuntar al caracter del centro de la string, supongo que fui poco claro y me disculpo por eso. Quisiera saber si puedes profundizar en la serie de if, como funciona. Y gracias nuevamente mi rey.

Comment: @Jose me pregunto para que quieres un vector de punteros cuando lo puedes hacer con un solo puntero. Por cierto, `*(A+i)` es equivalente a `A[i]`. Es más cómodo y legible escribirlo de la segunda manera, así que sugiero que lo hagan así. A menos que quieras aumentar el puntero al mismo tiempo que lees la información no me parece necesario, por ejemplo `*(puntero++)`.

Comment: @ Mateo Bueno, en realidad mi profesora lo quería de esa manera, asique no me quedaba de otra .